# Password verify not working with password hash BCRYPT

Tags: php, mysql, password-hash

I'm currently working on a PHP login, the password is encrypted on another file using `password_hash('password',PASSWORD_BCRYPT)`, I'm actually retrieving data from mySQL, and getting data from a AJAX call, but I have declared variables for showing my problem:

```
<?php
require "modulos/conexion.php";
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) && !isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    $usuario = "mariano overs";
    $pass = "1234";
    $passdb = '$2y$10$A1nr4od4OjP0N1hNoB9Seur3OsWzU3ufT4G82XNTLV3'; // equivalent of password_hash('1234',PASSWORD_BCRYPT), this is value from DB
    $sql = 'SELECT id_usua, co_usua, ds_pass FROM dbfar_cabusuarios WHERE co_usua="' . $usuario . '" LIMIT 1';
    if ($res = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conexion'],$sql)) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($res) == 1) {
            $usuario = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            echo "Contrasena guardada: ". $pass . "<br />Contrasena de la base: " . $usuario['ds_pass'] . "<br />";
            if (password_verify($pass, $passdb)){
                $_SESSION['username'] = $usuario['co_usua'];
                $_SESSION['userid'] = $usuario['id_usua'];
                echo "INICIO SESION CORRECTAMENTE";
            }
            else{
                echo "INICIO SESION NO CORRECTO";
            }

        } else {
            echo "REGISTROS NO CORRECTOS";
        }
    } else {
        echo "USUARIO NO EXISTE";
    }
}
```

Since I know I get the right value from database, is not the problem there, but on the password_verify function. They are not correctly validated. Is there an additional value I need to include on the `password_verify`?

Comment: No, you're using it correctly. Are there aqy errors in your error log?

Comment: what's the password column's length and type?

Comment: *"I've my money on that Sam"* ^ @JayBlanchard wanna take 10 to 1 odds? ;-)

Comment: *Sounds like a good 'un to me Ralph!* @Fred-ii-

Comment: I might have to get some of that fried chicken off you Sam @JayBlanchard the way it's going now.

Comment: I'll share @Fred-ii-

Comment: I'm getting hungrier by the minute Sam @JayBlanchard you've any Gumbo too?

Comment: I haven't checked error log, but field format is varchar(50)

Comment: @Forcefield as outlined in my answer. Your answer is in there ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- mySQL query doesn't throw any error when inserting, does it? *i will die slowly*

Comment: @Forcefield It will fail silently, yes because of it. Increase the column's size. Delete your stored hashes, alter your column to be long enough to accomodate the hash, store a new hash, then query again. It's all in my answer below.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I really will feel stupid, and this question will surely get downvoted :(

Comment: @Forcefield I doubt that and don't feel so bad. We should close the question and mark it as solved then, since my answer mentions everything that needs to be done.

Comment: @Fred-ii- where should I mark it as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hashed password holds a 60-72 character long string.

The column needs to be long enough in order to accomodate the hash.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

The manual suggests 255 in order to accomodate for the future.

You will need to start over and alter your column so that it is long enough.

Do that, store a new hash and start over.

60 characters: (from the manual)
`$2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNOgsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGv3Fykk1a`

and you have a 50 long: (there you go; too short)

`$2y$10$A1nr4od4OjP0N1hNoB9Seur3OsWzU3ufT4G82XNTLV3`

that tells me that it's been truncated.

The manual states:

**Caution**

Using the **PASSWORD_BCRYPT** as the algorithm, will result in the password parameter being truncated to a maximum length of 72 characters.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

---

As an added bonus:

Your code is prone to an SQL injection. Best to use a prepared statement.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement
- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: This was, in fact, the issue. Field length was 50, changed to 72 and works fine :)